# Serialize SQLAlchemy Objects that have children with multiple children

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have an SLQALchemy object that I am serializing with [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

The object has N likes and N comments. It looks like this:

```
class Parent():

    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    title = Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(db.String(500))
    created_at = Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    comments = relationship('Comment')
    likes = relationship('Like')
```

The serializers look like this:

```
class CommentSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'created_at', 'parent_id')

class LikeSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'parent_id')

class ParentSerializer(Serializer):
    comments = fields.Nested(CommentSerializer)
    likes = fields.Nested(LikeSerializer)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'comments', 'likes')
```

I try to run this in the view like so:

```
allParents = Parent.query.all()
```

And turn it into JSON with this:

```
return jsonify({"parents": ParentSerializer(allParents, many=True).data})
```

When I try and run that, I get an error `list indices must be integers, not str`. It comes from `marshmallow/serializer.py`. When I log some things in there, it appears that marshmallow is trying to access the `text` property of a list of `<Comment>`. It should be accessing each `<Comment>` individually then accessing the `text` property.

Am I missing something in my serializer(s)? I know sending the `many=True` argument in ParentSerializer tells marshmallow that it should iterate through a list of `<Parent>`. Is there a way to tell marshmallow that it should also expect many `<Comment>` or `<Like>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell marshmallow that it should also expect many `<Comment>` or `<Like>`?

Yes. You can also pass `many=True` to `Nested` fields.

```
class ParentSerializer(Serializer):
    comments = fields.Nested(CommentSerializer, many=True)
    likes = fields.Nested(LikeSerializer, many=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell marshmallow that it should also expect many `<Comment>` or `<Like>`?

Alternatively, you can do this:

```py
class ParentSerializer(Serializer):
    comments = fields.List(fields.Nested(CommentSerializer))
    likes = fields.List(fields.Nested(LikeSerializer))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object
and you can use your custom serialize function.

```
 class Company(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'company'

  id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
  name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  users = relationship("CompanyUser", back_populates="company")

  def serialize(self):
   main =  { c.key: getattr(self, c.key) for c in inspect(self).mapper.column_attrs }
   children = [user.serialize() for user in self.users] 
   main['users'] = children
   return  main
```

And, into the other model classes you can use this kind of "generic" serializable:

```
 def serialize(self):
    return { c.key: getattr(self, c.key) for c in inspect(self).mapper.column_attrs }
```